# Sscanf in a C++ (Read in values and assign simultaneously)

Tags: c++, file, scanf

Can I do something like this in C++ ?

```
//int i,Data[];
//malloc Data[];

$sscanf(line,"Data[%d]=0x%d",i,Data[i]);
```

Data[] is an int array and I am trying to read in random indices according to the value of 'i' I read in in one shot.

Comment: All parameters passed to a function are `completely` evaluated before the function is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
int index, value;
sscanf(line, "Data[%d]=%d", &index, &value);
// Check if index is within bounds of the array here
Data[index] = value;
```

You need the '&' because sscanf takes pointers as arguments.

Comment: Yeah..that's what I finally resorted to. Using a temp variable. But you know..I am not a big fan of temp variables.

Answer (score -1):

Why not try it yourself? Don't forget you need to pass pointers to your values i.e.

```
sscanf(line, "Data[%d]=0x%d", &i, &Data[i]);
```

Whether or not it works (and it for the record, it doesn't), it makes for much more readable / safe code to do the assignment with a separate call (what happens if `i` is greater than the end of the array?):

```
const int maxData = 10;
int Data[maxData];

int i;
int tmp;
sscanf(line, "Data[%d]=0x%d", &i, &tmp);

if( i >= maxData )
{
    printf("Error! index was too big");
}
else
{
    Data[i] = tmp;
}
```

**[Edit]** @ the down-voters: I know it doesn't work I was just trying to encourage the OP to try it for his/her self

Comment: This cannot work since `Data[i]` must be evaluated before the call to `sscanf`.